# Can I safe delete a github team without lose it's repositories?

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I want to delete some teams from my organization but I don't want to lose the repositories that is being shared to those. Could I safe delete those teams and still keep repositories within organization?

Comment: Whilst I would like to know the answer, this isn't a programming question. This is a github website question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. All your repos stay on github. These are not tied to a team. So you can safely delete it.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks for your help, Andy.